# Docker stats with CPU percentage more than 100

Tags: docker, cpu-usage, docker-container

I have a question about `docker stats` command if anyone can help me. I am new in Docker area and I want to monitor the cpu usage of a docker container.

The physical machine has 8 cores (CPU0...CPU7). I already create a container and limit its cpu resource to 1 core (CPU0) using the following command:
`docker run -itd --cpuset-cpus=0 -p 8081:8080 binfalse/bives-webapp`.

I stress the container by sending requests from Jmeter and then monitor the cpu usage of the container via `docker stats` command which gives me values greater than 100%.

I don't understand why it gives more than 100% even if only one core is allocated to the container! Do you have any idea about the reason? Does this cpu value represents the cpu usage of some system processes in addition to the container?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**docker version:**

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:23:31 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:19:04 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

**docker info result:**

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 10
Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 141
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
runc version: 2d41c047c83e09a6d61d464906feb2a2f3c52aa4
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-98-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.56GiB
Name: logti048131
ID: RHOG:IR6N:FVC4:YDI5:A6T4:QA4Y:DDYF:7HZN:AI3L:WVLE:BNHY:6YNV
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: What kernel and docker version are you running? Does `docker info` show any cgroup warnings? Can you describe more details on your load? I'm not able to reproduce this in my own lab with a simple while "true loop" in a bash shell. Rather than limiting to a physical cpu, consider using `--cpus=1.0` for the kernel scheduler.

Comment: @BMitch It's fairly accurate for me with 1 container. I do see it go up to 100.34 or 100.67% occasionally.  If I add 20 containers it ends up +-16%. Another 20 and it's +- 35%. Which is way out of whack with what the OS tracks.

Comment: All containers locked to the same core? All of them CPU bound, or just a single CPU bound container with lots of other idle containers?

Comment: 1 container cpu bound to 1 core using 100% of that core, lots of idle containers.  I've tried on Alpine and Debian VM's but not on metal yet. Looks like a bug to me so far.

Comment: @BMitch I added the docker version and the docker info output.

Comment: Github issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401648/docker-stats-with-cpu-percentage-more-than-100

Answer (score 15):

On Linux, cgroups and Docker CPU stats deal in "time slices" of CPU, the number of nanoseconds the CPU has been in use for. To get the percentage, the container cgroup value of "time used" is compared to the overall system value for "time available" from `/proc/stat`.

Due to the stored "time slice" values being cumulative, the current values are compared to the previous collected values to get a more instantaneous percentage. I think this comparison is the basis of the issue.

#### Stats Collection

The `docker stats` command actually does a lot of the leg work for this information in the client. The client queries for all containers, watches events for container start/stops and [opens an individual stats stream](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.33/#operation/ContainerStats) for each running container. These streams of container stats are used to [calculate the percentages](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/1401d5daf2f49a97791487dd5c5a8598907f0bf1/cli/command/container/stats_helpers.go#L168-L185) on each dump of stats data from a stream.

For the container stats stream, the Docker daemon collects the [systems used cpu time](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/76531ccdeb5850156150b88c6a4a56bb8c35dc44/daemon/stats/collector.go#L75) first. It then uses libcontainer to [read in a containers cgroup files and parse the text into values](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/52454cf90807727923b375afd7d84ac8fd523959/libcontainer/cgroups/fs/cpuacct.go#L72).  Here are [all the stats data structures](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/7139b61f7fdb904d0acb8db825709aa8d2d2ef36/libcontainer/cgroups/stats.go). That is all then sent to the client as a JSON response for processing.

I believe at least part of the problem stems from reading and parsing the `/proc/stat` system information and container cgroup stats at different times. Every time the goroutine that reads the container info is delayed a bit, more nanoseconds are included in that sample compared to the system. As the collection process is scheduled to run every X seconds, the next read then includes less total nanoseconds so the values can bounce up on a busy system, then back down the same amount as there is not a full 'tick' included in the second sample.

The issue compounds the more containers you run and the busier the system gets. The stats gathering and forwarding to the client seems to be a relatively heavyweight process, just `docker stats` with a large number of containers is enough to cause more inaccuracy. My best guess is contention in the goroutines that are all trying to read the stats.  I'm not sure that would account for quite the level of inaccuracy the Docker shows. I'm either completely wrong or there's something else adding to the problem.

#### Linux cgroups

Each Docker containers usage is tracked in a [cgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups). The CPU accounting information can be viewed via the cgroup file system:

```
→ find /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker -type d
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker/f0478406663bb57d597d4a63a031fc2e841de279a6f02d206b27eb481913c0ec
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker/5ac4753f955acbdf38beccbcc273f954489b2a00049617fdb0f9da6865707717
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker/a4e00d69819a15602cbfb4f86028a4175e16415ab9e2e9a9989fafa35bdb2edf
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker/af00983b1432d9ffa6de248cf154a1f1b88e6b9bbebb7da2485d94a38f9e7e15

→ cd /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker/f0478406663bb57d597d4a63a031fc2e841de279a6f02d206b27eb481913c0ec
→ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 22:31 cgroup.clone_children
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 04:35 cgroup.procs
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 21:51 cpuacct.stat
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 21:51 cpuacct.usage
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 22:31 cpuacct.usage_all
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 21:51 cpuacct.usage_percpu
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 22:31 cpuacct.usage_percpu_sys
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 22:31 cpuacct.usage_percpu_user
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 22:31 cpuacct.usage_sys
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 22:31 cpuacct.usage_user
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 22:31 notify_on_release
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 20 22:31 tasks

→ cat cpuacct.usage_percpu
3625488147 6265485043 6504277830
```

Each value is the cumulative usage in nano seconds on that CPU.

```
→ grep -w ^cpu /proc/stat
cpu  475761 0 10945 582794 2772 0 159 0 0 0
```

[Values here are `USER_HZ`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) == 1/100 of a second, so get some conversion in Docker.

Comment: @Alwansm Yes. sampling the cgroup CPU nanosecond time slice values every second for a stress-ng container bound to 1 cpu at the same time as docker, the readings rarely deviate from ~ 9999xxxxx ns which seems about right to me compared to `top`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula on how docker stats calculate the CPU percentage:

[Code from Docker Project](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/6c12a82f330675d4e2cfff4f8b89a353bcb1fecd/cli/command/container/stats_helpers.go#L180)

```
cpuPercent = (cpuDelta / systemDelta) * onlineCPUs * 100.0
```

where the Deltas are calculated as `currentCPUUsage - previousCPUUsage`